# Updating Ink Annotation using PDFKit in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, annotations, ios11, pdfkit

I want the user to draw and create an Ink annotation on the pdf document using pdfkit for iOS 11.

I am recording the touches of the user and draw using the bezier path. I am able to add the annotation to the desired position. 
I am facing a problem when the user is zooming the pdf and try to update the annotation. That time I am redrawing the annotation using the saved bezier paths but they are drawn at a different location than the previously drawn location.[PFA Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGxmI.jpg)
[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNkMW.png)

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: @Dominique I have added a canvas view to capture user touches and draw the lines using bazier path. I am converting user touch point to the PDFView with `- (PDFPoint)convertPoint:(PDFPoint)point toPage:(PDFPage *)page` and then adding that UIBezierPath to ink annotation.
When user want to edit the comment and if the pdfview is zoomed then at that time the annotation getting placed  at different location on canvas view because canvas view starting point (0,0) is at diffrent location than that of pdfview.

Comment: @Dominique Please check updated screenshot.

Comment: Without adding source code it would be really hard to help you.